# Using a client-side datetime picker in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

Right now, I have a simple `<%= date_select(:record, :date, ampm: false) %>` in my view. For the past few days, I've been trying to implement a datetime viewer, and just can't grasp it. I've looked at [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/), [Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), and others. I understand the jQuery behind them - it's simple to just apply a class to an `<input>` field.

What I don't understand is how the date gets correctly passed as a part of my Rails form. For example, pickadate.js applies a class to an `<input>` field, but how does my `form_for` recognize what attribute it's for? When I use a `date_select(:record, :date)`, I'm telling my app that the input should be recorded in the record model as the date attribute, right? How do I do this with a client-side `<input>` field?

Comment: I'm working with the `Record` model `date` attribute. From messing around with it, I've found that if I create my input field like this, it seems to work:

`<input class = "datepicker" name = "record[date]" id = "record_date">`

Comment: it knows what attribute your input is for based on the name of the input. In this case, its "record[date]". Rails use "model[attribute]" in the input name to identify attributes. If you use the 'text_field' helper for another attribute, using an inspector, you will also see the same naming convention in the html generated.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-form-helpers. This explains better than me.